# What data type to use for storing version numbers in database in Django

Tags: django, django-models

What is the best data type to use for storing version data such as x.x.x ( ex: 1.1.0) using the django model fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a string.  Pretty easy to manage and flexible.  Make sure that you stick to your convention though if you do any parsing or manipulating of the string because depending on how you plan to use it like (version 1) > (version 2) then x.x.x != x.xx.x.